# Tsql union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, window-functions

I’m looking for an efficient way to query a table.
The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CaseManager](
    [CaseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SystemUserCreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [SystemUserAssignee] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Case] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CaseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The query should return for every caseID and userid (userid can be either SystemUserCreatedBy or SystemUserAssignee) bit columns that show if the use is Createdby or Assignee
I managed to write it like this:

```
select  CaseID,UserID,
       max(CaseUser.IsAssignee) as IsAssignee,
       max(CaseUser.IsCreator) as IsCreator


  FROM
  (
  select CMassignee.CaseID,
         CMassignee.SystemUserAssignee as UserID,
         1 as IsAssignee ,
         0 as IsCreator 
      from CaseManager CMassignee 
  where  CMassignee.SystemUserAssignee is not null
  UNION
   select CMCreator.CaseID,
          CMCreator.SystemUserCreatedBy as UserID,
          0 as IsAssignee ,
          1 as IsCreator 
      from CaseManager CMCreator
  where  CMCreator.SystemUserCreatedBy is not null
    ) CaseUser
  group by CaseID,UserID
```

I’m pretty sure there is a better way to write it with scanning that table once .In that example I show only two columns (SystemUserCreatedBy as SystemUserAssignee) but actually I have five that need to be added.

Please see example of data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.casemanager ON;
insert into casemanager(caseid,SystemUserCreatedBy,SystemUserAssignee)
values
(1,2222,3333)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.casemanager OFF;
```

In that case I’m looking to get :

```
CaseID      UserID      IsAssignee  IsCreator
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2222        0           1
1           3333        1           0

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: "either SystemUserCreatedBy or SystemUserAssignee" is this an exclusive OR, always only one of both will be NOT NULL?

Comment: It's good that you added the required output... there was quite a debate about that during your absence :-)

Comment: SystemUserCreatedBy and SystemUserAssignee are nullable columns.

Comment: There was no problem with the nullable columns, the question was if a row like (1,2222,3333) should be split to 2 result rows. Now you made that clear.

Comment: And now the next question is: Can `SystemUserCreatedBy` and `SystemUserAssignee` be the same user for a `CaseID`?

Comment: Yes then can.   example : insert into casemanager(caseid,SystemUserCreatedBy,SystemUserAssignee)
values
(1,2222,2222)

Answer (score 1):

The `CaseID` is the Primary Key, so there's no need for aggregation (if only one of both columns is NOT NULL):

```
SELECT
   CaseID,
   COALESCE(SystemUserAssignee, SystemUserCreatedBy) AS UserID,
   CASE WHEN SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 end AS IsAssignee,
   CASE WHEN SystemUserCreatedBy IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 end AS IsCreator
FROM CaseManager CMassignee
```

Edit:

Based on the latest comments both columns can have data and it might be the same user, so your original query is ok (even if it scans the table twice), the only thing you need to change is `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

But for 5 userid @Amit's answer should be the best.

Comment: I like the use of COALESCE - shows my developer bias that I never remember that.  I'd add the where clause to enforce the condition you describe (but don't implement) in your answer.

Comment: Imagine you have 1 row   user1, user2. The op's query will return 2 rows : user1 1 0 and user2 0 1. Your query will return user1 1 1. I think it is not what op wants.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: That's why I wrote *"if only one of both columns is NOT NULL"*. The OP didn't tell exactly plus *"actually I have five that need to be added"*...

Comment: That is an overly verbose, complicated, wasteful solution. Read OP again - the intentions are to have 5 "userid" columns, and 5 flags. You'd get 32 (2^5) selects & unions. Very slow, totally unmaintainable.

Comment: @Amit: I actually forgot about the 5 columns, of course then the last query is stupid, I was just trying to avoid the aggregation. I will vote up your answer if you add the final GROUP BY :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - What GROUP BY is missing? I think my answer gives the requested result (Did I misunderstand something, again? :-)

Comment: @Amit: The original query returned one row per `UserID` / `CaseId` combination. As the same user might be in more than one column the final `GROUP BY` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using CASE statements

```
SELECT CaseID,
       CASE
         WHEN SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL THEN SystemUserAssignee
         ELSE SystemUserCreatedBy
       END as UserID,
       CASE
         WHEN SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as IsAssignee,
       CASE
         WHEN SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END as IsCreator
FROM CaseManager
WHERE SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL OR SystemUserCreateBy IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Still you need to group here. But this is simply incorrect. If one row contains 2 different users you just picking one and lose info of second user.

Comment: OP wanted to split rows where `SystemUserAssignee` and `SystemUserCreatedBy` to 2 rows in the result set, with the appropriate flag for each row

Comment: See my comment to dnoent's answer

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri He stated in the question that it could be either/or not both.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I'm with GiorgiNakeuri.. Look at OP solution (which is stated to work as desired). It splits the rows.

Comment: Only if both can be null at the same time - the OP seems to indicate that won't be the case.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I understand the exact opposite... your solution is incompatible when both are NOT NULL. In that case, OP splits the row to 2 result rows. (P.S. Adding my own answer that accommodates this)

Comment: @amit `userid can be either SystemUserCreatedBy or SystemUserAssignee` - quoting directly from the question.  I understand that the query will operate differently if that's not the case but the OP knows his data.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying it can be interpreted in 2 ways (If you try to read that full sentence assuming my understanding is correct, it will still make sense). Unfortunately for all of us, user3006397 is not reading this :-)

Comment: @amit Fair enough, but I'd probably pull both columns rather than generating an extra row if that were the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CaseID ,
        CASE WHEN SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL THEN SystemUserAssignee
             ELSE SystemUserCreatedBy
        END AS UserID ,
        CASE WHEN SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS IsAssignee ,
        CASE WHEN SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL THEN 0
             ELSE 1
        END AS IsAssignee
FROM    CaseManager;
```

Comment: after formating using SSMS tools, look exactly like @tvanfosson answer

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by joining a "static table" to duplicate each row the necessary amount of times (2 in this sample, but can be expanded to any number).

```
SELECT CaseID, UserID, MAX(IsCreator) IsCreator, MAX(IsAssignee) IsAssignee
FROM (


  SELECT CaseID, CASE
    WHEN Switcher = 1 THEN SystemUserCreatedBy
    WHEN Switcher = 2 THEN SystemUserAssignee
    END AS UserID,
    IIF(Switcher = 1, 1, 0) AS IsCreator,
    IIF(Switcher = 2, 1, 0) AS IsAssignee
  FROM dbo.CaseManager CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2)) switcher(Switcher)
  WHERE (SystemUserCreatedBy IS NOT NULL AND Switcher = 1) OR
    (SystemUserAssignee IS NOT NULL AND Switcher = 2)


) sub
GROUP BY CaseID, UserId
ORDER BY CaseID, UserId
```

The idea is that the switcher table has a row for each of the flags, and then the main `SELECT` query uses this value to pick the right values for each row.

> EDIT: As rightfully mentioned by dnoeth, I had to wrap the query with a grouping to match OP. I thought this was distracting from the main idea of  the answer and so this part of the solution is "separated" by empty lines.

Also available: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d873/7)

*Note: The `VALUES(1),(2)` syntax is only available in SQL SERVER 2008 +

> EDIT 2: I've had  a second thought about the solution, and came up with a more elegant query. I'm not sure which version will turn up quicker, and I believe the original version could be useful in other scenarios so I'm keeping both.

Version 2:

```
SELECT CaseID, UserID, IsCreator=IIF(UserID=SystemUserCreatedBy, 1, 0),
 IsAssignee=IIF(UserID=SystemUserAssignee, 1, 0)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT *, CASE
    WHEN Switcher = 1 THEN SystemUserCreatedBy
    WHEN Switcher = 2 THEN SystemUserAssignee
    END AS UserID
  FROM dbo.CaseManager CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2)) switcher(Switcher)
) sub
WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CaseID, UserId
```

And the updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d873/14)