# Show different fields on one when, despite multiple IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**This is how the table looks:**

```
CountryId   CountryName    MemberType
143           AUT                1
171           AUT                2
202           AUT                3
206           BE                 1
```

**And this is the result I get when i run my query:**

```
CountryName   IsType1   IsType2
   AUT          Y          N
   AUT          N          Y
   AUT          N          N
   BE           Y          N
```

My problem is that I want it to only show one row per countryname. That says if it is type1 and type 2. But there is multiple CountryId for each CountryName, so I dont know what to do.

**This is how I want it:**

```
CountryName   IsType1   IsType2
AUT             Y          Y
BE              Y          N
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
SELECT 
 CountryName=c.CountryCode_ISO3166
,IsType1=CASE WHEN cm.CountryMemberTypeId = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end
,IsType2=CASE WHEN cm.CountryMemberTypeId = 2 then 'Y' else 'N' end


FROM static.Country c
inner JOIN static.CountryMemberOfType cmem ON C.CountryId = cmem.CountryId
inner join static.CountryMemberType cm on cm.CountryMemberTypeId=cmem.CountryMemberTypeId
order by CountryCode_ISO3166
```

Comment: _"when i run my query"_ which query? Also, why does this query return `AT` for `AUT`, is that desired?

Comment: How come AUT is suddenly AT when you run your query? Can you show us your query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tsql union query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630257/tsql-union-query) (I'd advise to look at my answer in that question :-)

Comment: How many IsTypeX columns do you want to have? Just two or as many as there are possible values for MemberType?

Comment: Just three columns, one for the countryname, and one to check if countryname has value 1 and one to check if countryname has value 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select CountryName,
       case when sum(case when MemberType = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
            then 'Y' else 'N' end as IsType1,
       case when sum(case when MemberType = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
            then 'Y' else 'N' end as IsType2
from Tablename
group by CountryName
```